# Unable to save ML model to Google Drive in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

Here is the function that I am using to save the model. The folder 'models' does not exist. But shouldn't it create a folder 'models' and save the model with a filename as written. I cannot find a solution for this anywhere.

```
# Create a function to save a model
def save_model(model, suffix=None):
  """
  Saves a given model in a models directory and appends a suffix (str)
  for clarity and reuse.
  """
  # Create model directory with current time
  modeldir = os.path.join("/content/drive/My Drive/Dog Eyes/models/",
                          datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%s"))
  model_path = modeldir + "-" + suffix + ".h5" # save format of model
  print(f"Saving model to: {model_path}...")
  model.save(model_path)
  return model_path
```

And I am calling the function like

```
# Save our model trained on 1000 images
save_model(model, suffix="1000-images-mobilenetv2-Adam")
```

Here is the error that I am getting when executing the function

```
Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = '/content/drive/My Drive/Dog Eyes/models/20200306-18501583520636-1000-images-mobilenetv2-Adam.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 13, o_flags = 242)
```

The complete error message

```
Saving model to: /content/drive/My Drive/Dog Eyes/models/20200306-18501583520636-1000-images-mobilenetv2-Adam.h5...

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-62-d56ea448536c> in <module>()
----> 1 save_model(model, suffix="1000-images-mobilenetv2-Adam")

5 frames

/tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/h5py/_hl/files.py in make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr)
    177         fid = h5f.create(name, h5f.ACC_EXCL, fapl=fapl, fcpl=fcpl)
    178     elif mode == 'w':
--> 179         fid = h5f.create(name, h5f.ACC_TRUNC, fapl=fapl, fcpl=fcpl)
    180     elif mode == 'a':
    181         # Open in append mode (read/write).

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/h5f.pyx in h5py.h5f.create()

OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = '/content/drive/My Drive/Dog Eyes/models/20200306-18501583520636-1000-images-mobilenetv2-Adam.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 13, o_flags = 242)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder 'models' was not created and that seems to have been the issue. Manually creating the 'models' folder would fix the issue and the model would get saved in the correct path

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
model_path = 'saved_model/my_model_1'

model.save_pretrained(model_path)
tokenizer.save_pretrained(model_path)
```

or

```py
model_path = 'saved_model/my_model_1.h5'

model.save_pretrained(model_path)
tokenizer.save_pretrained(model_path)
```

To check:

```
!mkdir -p saved_model
```

To inspect the saved model:

```
!ls saved_model
```

To check if it contains an assets folder, saved_model.pb, and variables folder.

```
!ls my_model_1.h5
```

Comment: The formatting of this answer is quite confusing.  Please put the code in code blocks, and consistently format the headers.